# TFS2010 web - Send notification to user who logged the work item

Tags: tfs

How can i send notification to user about accepting the work item?

i have send notification to me, but how do i send the email to user who logged the work item?

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You requirements are a bit to complex to be handled out of the box. Please take a look at the Event Notification Plugin for TFS2010 hosted at codeplex under project name Team Alert: http://teamalert.codeplex.com/.

> *It is a server side extension for TFS 2010, which allows you sending E-Mail notifications to any person field in the event, regardless the field contain a SID, account name or display name.*

The creator talks about your very needs on his own website: http://fszlin.dymetis.com/post/2011/03/22/Event-Notification-Plugin-for-TFS-2010.aspx.

The configuration for you could be something like this:

```
<alert  name="Bug Changes"  event="WorkItemChangedEvent"
 filterExpression="$&quot;CoreFields/StringFields/Field [ReferenceName='System.WorkItemType']/NewValue&quot; = Bug AND $&quot;CoreFields/StringFields/Field[ReferenceName='System.AuthorizedAs']/NewValue&quot; &lt;&gt; $&quot;CoreFields/StringFields/Field[ReferenceName='System.CreatedBy']/NewValue&quot;">
 <recipients>
  <recipient
   name="Owner" address="CoreFields/StringFields/Field[ReferenceName='System.CreatedBy']/NewValue"
   type="DisplayNameField"
   allowHtml="true"/>
 </recipients>
</alert>
```

Does that solve your needs?

Comment: If it can detect user from Active directory and take it from ad record and therefore user does not need to provide email..

Comment: That is the described behavior, yes. See quote in answer: regardless the field contain a SID, account name or display name